# Generic function to pop or dismiss ViewController in iOS & iPadOS just like show() & showDetail()

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, uisplitviewcontroller

Just like we have `show(_ vc: UIViewController, sender: Any?)` & `showDetailViewController(_ vc: UIViewController, sender: Any?)` to push & present ViewControllers irrespective of the case whether they are embedded in UINavigationController or UISplitController.

Do we have something generic just like these to pop/dismiss a ViewController ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you're asking...

There is a `UIViewController` function called `dismiss(animated: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)?)` and navigationController?.popViewController(animated: `Bool`).

if you're looking for something that would do either, I'd imagine it would look something like

```
extension UIViewController {
    func dismissPop(animated: Bool) {
        if let navigationController = navigationController {
            navigationController.popViewController(animated: animated)
        } else {
            dismiss(animated: animated)
        }
    }
}
```

A completion handler could be added as well if necessary.